# How to easily understand normalization - Database

Tags: sql, database

I have gone through lot of sites to understand normalization but it seems like I have to memorize the rules. After a week or later I forget it and seems like every thing is new for me.

Is any better way to understand the first three normal forms. I need some easy practical examples to understand and remember it always.

For now I know,

```
1st Normal Form - Remove Repeating groups (should be Atomic).
2nd Normal Form - Remove partial Dependency.
3rd Normal Form - Remove transitive Dependency.
```

Comment: For me, normalization is "store the data once and use joins if you need to access it".

Comment: Yes exactly, but what about different normal forms. I am struggling to answer the question asked by one of our client.(What is the maximum normal form you implemented in your database).

Comment: You'd need to look at your tables one by one. IMHO 4th and 5th level forms are rarely required by clients, so I would look for tables that violate 2nd or 3rd normal form. Might be a good opportunitiy to improve your DB structure if you find any. [This is a fairly simple guide](http://www.bkent.net/Doc/simple5.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good explanation [on Dream in Code](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/179103-relational-database-design-normalization/).

For examples, try remembering the most common violations:

1. First and last name in a single field
2. Storing name and price of an item along with the order for that item
3. Storing an address with a customer record

Comment: Thanks Neil, The document you shared looks simple for me to understand. Give me an example for your third (Storing an address with a customer record) point.

Comment: The idea would be to store data in a way that all data in a table changes at the same "rate". In other words, I can change my address without changing my name and birthday, so I break out that information into a separate table.

Answer (score 1):

The first nomal form should be clear. **You have atomic values and create redundancy in your table**. At this point it means: Your current primary keys are not longer unique.

The 2NF means that you should elimnate redundant data. The attributes **need to be functional dependent to your primary key and not to other non-prime attributes**. If they are not dependent to your primary key, your table isn't in the second NF.

The 3NF is imho a bit more difficult. I just read about an other definition of it. So usually you have: Your attributes must not be dependent transitively to your primary key. **The transition means, that your attribute shouldn't refer to your primary key through an other attribute.** Let's have a look at an example:

```
| CourseNr    | Course Name         | ProfNr| ProfName  |
---------------------------------------------------------
10            | Analysis            | 90    | A         |
12            | Math                | 90    | A         |
16            | Databases           | 65    | D         |
17            | Literature          | 68    | F         |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

But now you have a transitive dependency from ProfName to CourseName, because your ProfName depends "over" ProfNr to CourseNr. Your prof's name isn't necessary for your table and you have redundancy. Now you can extract that to:

```
| ProfNr | ProfName |
---------------------
| 90     | A        |
| 65     | D        |
| 68     | F        |
---------------------
```

And now you can delete the ProfName row in your first table. Your redundancyhas been eliminated and you can link your prof via the ProfNr.

And your first table looks like this now:

```
| CourseNr    | Course Name         | ProfNr |
----------------------------------------------
10            | Analysis            | 90     |
12            | Math                | 90     |
16            | Databases           | 65     |
17            | Literature          | 68     |
----------------------------------------------
```

For me: I have always an easy example in my head for the third NF, because it's for me the NF I had problems with.

Comment: Thanks Zumarata, but its hard to understand the technical terms like transitive, partial and full dependency

Comment: Hm, I see. For the transitive dependencies: You could see this like a relation. To prevent the word transitive, use relation: ProfName doesn't relate to your CourseNr by itself, but you have the relation to it, because the ProfName relates to the ProfNr and the ProfNr then relates to the CourseNr. So you ProfName relates to your CourseNr "over" this ProfNr. And that relation is the transition which shall not exist. Does this help you?

Answer (score 1):

**in first normalization** form there should be no redundancy i.e the values should be atomic
ex:              `1 Rahul   Computer Networks, Designing`

here Computer Networks, Designing should not come in same column, since it isn't producing atomicity .the values should be like

```
     1. 1   Rahul   Computer Networks
     2. 1   Rahul   Designing`
```

avoiding redundancy

**in Second normalization** form there should be no partial dependency and it should be in 1NF.
**Partial Dependency** :few attributes of the candidate key determines non-prime
attribute(s).
In other words,

```
     A → B is called a partial dependency if and only if-
     1. A is a subset of some candidate key
     2. B is a non-prime attribute.

     If any one condition fails, then it will not be a partial dependency.
```

**in Third Normalization** form: there should not be any transitive dependency and also should be in 2NF.
**Transitive Dependency**:A → B is called a transitive dependency if and only if-
1. A is not a super key.
2. B is a non-prime attribute.
If any one condition fails, then it is not a transitive dependency.

A relation is in 3NF if at least one of the following condition holds in every non-trivial function dependency X –> Y

```
    X is a super key.
    Y is a prime attribute (each element of Y is part of some candidate key)
```

**BCNF** :A relation is in BCNF if in every non-trivial functional dependency

```
    X –> Y, X is a super key.
```